# Outdoor activities in San Francisco when it's misty and raining?

Tags: weather, rain

I'm spending the weekend in San Francisco, and after a week indoors at a conference I'm keen to do something outside. My plan had been to ride the trolley down to Fisherman's Wharf, hire a bike and cycle to the Presidio, across the Golden Gate Bridge, up into the Golden Gate National Recreation Area, then down to Sausalito. I've done this before in nice weather and it's a really great trip! Unfortunately, it's set to misty and raining this weekend, and I'm not sure it'll work so well with fog hiding most of the views...

Are there any outdoor activities to do in San Francisco that do work well on misty and rainy days? (Specifically, ones that can be reached without a car, and are suitable for a touristy half day rather than a new sport to get into over time)

Comment: I think this question belongs better at outdoor SE — should have a better chance of being answered there.

Comment: I think it's on topic for both. In theory we know locations better but they know the outdoors better. In reality there's surely more SE users in the USA and possibly in the Bay Area. Let's see how it goes and migrate it if it doesn't work here.

Comment: I live North of the city and I really love the redwoods on foggy mornings. Try getting out to Muir Woods, maybe. OR, if you're feeling really adventurous, drive the hour North and go hit Point Reyes National Seashore. It's beautiful there all the time, and I'm particularly smitten on a foggy morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one on your list that is no fun when wet is the Golden Gate visit.

The following are all do-able on foot - I used the trolley cars as part of my exploration when I went to see the following:

- The trolley car to fisherman's wharf is a good idea.
- The Coit Tower is good for a walk around
- Haight-Ashbury can be fun for a half day or so
- Lombard Street is the essential photo spot